# XML , XLST value is not populated

Tags: .net, xml, xslt

I am not able to read the below attribute value ("AttributeValue") from the xslt, Am I doing anything wrong by using

<---- here I am not able to paste the xml format code---it says not formatted properly though it is --> added in the below comments both xml and xslt

```
<MonthlyReport>
  <lstAttributes>
    <Attributes>
      <AttributeName>Stories</AttributeName>
      <AttributeValue>2000</AttributeValue>
    </Attributes>
  </lstAttributes>
</MonthlyReport>


<xsl:template match="/MonthlyReport">
<html>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="lstAttributes/Attributes/AttributeName='Stories'">
            <xsl:value-of select="AttributeValue"/>
          </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: If its an attribute, and in current scope, you need `@AttributeValue`. Please provide more context to your question.

Comment: added xml and xslt , how to get the attributevalue element value of stories attribute name element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are testing `lstAttributes/Attributes/AttributeName` but then attempting to select `AttributeValue` which is not in current scope (when entering this template, we are still at the `/MonthlyReport`) scope. Given that you don't have an `otherwise` in your choose, you might try instead:

```
<xsl:template match="/MonthlyReport">
<html>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of 
      select="lstAttributes/Attributes[AttributeName='Stories']/AttributeValue"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</html>
</xsl:template>
```

This will leave the `td` empty if nothing is found.

If you did want to do something different in an `otherwise`, you would need to repeat the full path (unless you bring `lstAttributes/Attributes` into current):

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="lstAttributes/Attributes/AttributeName='Stories'">
     <xsl:value-of select="lstAttributes/Attributes/AttributeValue"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:text>No Stories present</xsl:text>
   </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
```

Note that of course all the `Attribute*` are actually *elements*, hence the initial confusion about *attributes* in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Given input XML like:

```
<item name="foo">contents</item>
```

If the context node is `item`, then the path to the attribute value is `@name`. If the context node is `@item`, then the path to the attribute value `.`.

```
<xsl:template select="item">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template select="@name">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: my xml format is different not the one u have given example  < MonthlyReport>
 < lstAttributes>
     <Attributes>
      < AttributeName>Stories< /AttributeName>
      < AttributeValue>2000< /AttributeValue>
    < /Attributes>
 <lstAttributes>
< /MonthlyReport>                                                                                                                       < xsl:choose>
                < xsl:when test="lstAttributes/Attributes/AttributeName='Stories'">
                         < xsl:value-of select="AttributeValue"/>
                < /xsl:when>
              < /xsl:choose>

Comment: OK - you aren't actually using XML attributes at all, they're just elements confusingly named attribute. Format your xml with code blocks - i.e. each line indented 4 spaces, then it will be readable.

Comment: added the xml and xslt, here how to get the attributevalue of stories attributename